# Display GPX in Google Maps or other simple application?

Tags: google-maps, offline-map

I need an application that supports the following features:

- offline map (no Internet connection)
- bookmarks (POIs added by me from either my PC -> KML or in the app itself)

Since (Google) Maps doesn't currently support bookmarks, I use [MapsWithMe Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapswithme.maps.pro&hl=en) which does (along with offline maps).

I now need to import a GPX trace before going on a bike trip.

MapsWithMe doesn't support GPX yet, and failed importing KML files as converted with either [GPSVisualizer](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/gpsbabel/) or [Gpx2Kml](http://gpx2kml.com/).

I then tried [Locus Map Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=menion.android.locus) and [OsmAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand), but found them way too complicated for my need.

So... is there a way to simply display a GPX file in Google Maps on top of an offline map (no Internet connection available), or some other app that's a no-brainer to use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is working perfectly fine e.g. with [Locus Maps](http://www.appbrain.com/app/locus-map-free/menion.android.locus), as I can say from my own experience. You can even use KMZ files − and if they are self-contained (i.e. all pictures etc. are inside the file, no external resources linked), you can even create your own travel guides (I did that, works like a charm). The offline maps can be selected and downloaded for free from inside the app as well.

Comment: Thanks. I gave Locus Maps a second try and it does look like what I was after, although its screen is busier than MwM.